# How to open window or whatever while my method is doing something in background WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, freeze

as much as we know, 
programs are executing line by line, and now I am facing issue, I have a method which is taking few seconds to execute,
I thought I could solve it by threads but I will speak about it later, now what I would like to do is next:

How could I open a window with message like "Still executing..." when that method start execution and when method is done window could close himself,
I need that because I Would like to avoid UI freezing because that long method is not in another task/thread.

Here is how it looks like:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    //Could I show window here like like "Loading please wait.."
    ExecuteLongMethod();
    //When this is done close this method
}
```

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: How would that window with "Still executing..." avoid UI freezing?

Comment: @user3292642 because he would be shown there until something is happening in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ExecuteLongMethod()` must be executed on the dispatcher thread for some reason, you could create a new window that launches in a separate thread and display this one during the time it takes for the long-running method to complete. Please refer to the following link for more information.

[Wait screen during rendering UIElement in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698192/wait-screen-during-rendering-uielement-in-wpf/42700592#42700592)

The other option would otherwise be to execute the long-running method on a background thread and display the loading window on the main thread.

The recommended way to do this would be to use the task parallel library (TPL) and start a task: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    Window window = new Window();
    window.Show();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExecuteLongMethod())
    .ContinueWith(task => 
    {   
        window.Close();
    },System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: what does System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); means?  and is it possible that this can stay somewhere in processes or wherver, somewhere out of my application?

Comment: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() makes sure that the ContinueWith delegate (window.Close()) gets executed on the UI thread: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/09/22/taskscheduler-fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext/. System.Threading.CancellationToken.None and TaskContinuationOptions.None are default arguments that gets passed to the ContinueWith method.

Comment: is this what is called threading? or ? I am gonna read link you provided right now, you are great and awesome, thank you mm8

Comment: Yes, the Task.Factory.StartNew creates and starts a task that is eventually being executed on a thread pool thread using the default TaskScheduler.

Answer (score 1):

An example where a top window/control is displayed with progress information and the main window is disabled:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    // create a window with a progress ring or progress bar
    var window = new Window();

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        // execute long method
        ExecuteLongMethod();

        // close the progress window - release control
        // ensure it is done on the UI thread
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => window.Close());
    }).Start();

    // display progress window
    window.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Another approach would be to temporarily disable or hide any UI elements (buttons, tabs) that might interfere with the background thread and do not block the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Use the await-pattern

```
    public void YourMethod()
    {


        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            //Could I show window here like like "Loading please wait.."
            FireAndForget();
            //When this is done close this method
        }
    }

    public async void FireAndForget()
    {

        await Task.Run(() => { ExecuteLongMethod(); });

    }
```

Fire and forget is an antipattern so, but sometimes u face problems where you cant await forever - like in `Commands`.

If you want to wait for a Result or till its finished go like this

```
public async void YourMethodAsync()
{


    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        //Could I show window here like like "Loading please wait.."
        await CorrectWayAsync();
        //When this is done close this method
    }
}



public async Task CorrectWayAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { ExecuteLongMethod(); });
}
```